# Jquery cookie plugin wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

is the plugin. The code I have is this http://pastebin.com/4LkcGqMm

upon running, it gives this output

```
GET file:///C:/core/jquey.cookie.js  index.html:7
Loading game Game.js:31
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method       'cookie' Game.js:32
loadGame Game.js:32
onload index.html:9
Saving game Game.js:25
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Game.js:26
saveGame Game.js:26
Saving game
```

as you see, there are errors and the last lines of loadGame and saveGame are not being called. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link jQuery cookie to your script. You would include the script in your webpage by placing this into your header:

```
<head>
    <!-- Header Stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/Game.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jQueryCookie.js"></script>
    <!-- More Header Stuff -->
</head>
```

You must include the jQuery Cookie javascript class on every page you are adding Game.js as a script

---

Edit: 1

Also, it looks like you are using the cookie function wrong. IIRC, the proper way to reference the jQuery cookie class is `$.cookie`, not `cookie`

---

Edit: 2

The error is saying you are converting a circular structure to JSON. An example of that would be

```
a = {}
a.b = a;
```

In the above code, you are trying to set a part of A to A itself. I really can't tell which class is causing the error unless you provide **All the files** that I requested. (Intro(), MainMenu(), and CharacterCreate())

Comment: it is included, i include jquery and the plugin in the head and Game.js at tho bottom of the body along with my other js files.

Comment: @Makerimages-New Oh, I didn't see that :). What are the classes of Intro, MainMenu, and CharacterCreate?

Comment: Intro, for example http://pastebin.com/u124jybb the others are similar, but draw different things(objects of classes and so on)